# Why doesn't the C++11 compiler complain when I initialize a local variable with the same name multiple times within the same scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, initialization

So if I initialize a variable of the same type and name within the main function the compiler will complain of the re declaration, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int a{5};
    int a{5}; // error int a previously declared here
}
```

But there are no errors if I compile this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int a{5};
}
```

To my understanding, this looks as if I have initialized "int a" multiple times within the same scope which obviously would cause an error. If somebody could explain what's actually happening it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Note that this isn't specific to the g++ compiler. It is part of the C++ language specification.

Comment: Are you asking why the scope of the loop body doesn't count multiple times?

Comment: You are initializing `a` each time the loop runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing scope and lifetime, it seems.

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
> {
>     int a{5};
> }
> ```
>
> To my understanding, this looks as if I have initialized "int a"
>   multiple times within the same scope which obviously would cause an
>   error.

Why would that obviously cause an error? `a` is always the **same variable**, in every iteration of the loop. But it always points to a **different object**, whose lifetime begins and ends with the current iteration.

If such a thing would not work, then you could not even call the same function two times:

```
void f()
{
    int x = 0;
}

f();
f(); // why should this be an error?
```

Note that this question goes far beyond g++, and even far beyond C++. Every C-derived programming language works exactly like that. At least I've never seen one which doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

> To my understanding, this looks as if I have initialized "int a" multiple times within the same scope

You are right about the "multiple times" part, but you are wrong about "same scope": the scope of the second `int a` is *nested* inside the outer scope, in which the first `int a` is declared. Hence, the second declaration is legal: it hides the outer declaration, which the language allows.

```
int a = 5;
cout << a << endl;
{
    int a = 6;
    cout << a << endl;
}
cout << a << endl;
```

Demo above [produces](http://ideone.com/2d4EDi) this output:

```
5
6
5
```

Comment: I don't see where the OP had an `int a` in an outer scope. I think the OP is asking about the multiple loop iterations each declaring an `int a{5};` variable, saying they're all defined in the same scope (the loop body). The second loop iteration is not nested in the first.

Comment: No, "the new initialization are just nested deeper with each loop iteration" is not the correct explanation.

Comment: @n.m. There is no such thing as "loop iteration" in the program space (it's in the time space that loop iterations become relevant). Loop is one of many ways to open a nested scope; that's all there is to it.

Comment: @hvd He nests the second declaration in a nested scope, which happens to be opened by `for` loop. The fact that there is a loop is irrelevant to the explanation of why the second declaration is allowed.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In the second case, the second declaration is of a variable named `a`. The loop variable is named `i`. There is no `a` anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think your getting confused with declaring variable and initializing it

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int a{5}; // In this part you are declaring and initializing the variable
    int a{5}; // error int a previously declared here
    // same with this case as well
}
```

If you want to do that you can use this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
         int a{5}; 
         a=5; // error int a previously declared here

     }
```

at this point `int a{5}` This will be the declaration of a variable and initialization of  variable in the for loop scope

and `a=5;` and here reinitialize that particular variable in the same scope